# Pass a typed function as a parameter in Dart

Tags: functional-programming, dart

I know the [Function](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.1/dart-core/Function-class.html) class can be passed as a parameter to another function, like this:

```
void doSomething(Function f) {
    f(123);
}
```

But is there a way to constrain the arguments and the return type of the function parameter?

For instance, in this case `f` is being invoked directly on an integer, but what if it was a function accepting a different type?

I tried passing it as a `Function<Integer>`, but Function is not a parametric type.

Is there any other way to specify the signature of the function being passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Dart v1.23 added a new syntax for writing function types which also works in-line.

```dart
void doSomething(Function(int) f) {
  f(123);
}
```

It has the advantage over the function-parameter syntax that you can also use it for variables or anywhere else you want to write a type.

```dart
void doSomething(Function(int) f) {
  Function(int) g = f;
  g(123);
}

var x = <int Function(int)>[];

int Function(int) returnsAFunction() => (int x) => x + 1;
    
int Function(int) Function() functionValue = returnsAFunction;
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Anyways, this answers only first half of the question. How about the return types?

Comment: Added example of a return type which is a function type.

Comment: StreamSubscription<T> listen(void onData(T event),
      {Function onError, void onDone(), bool cancelOnError}); - why are 2 different notations are used? What's the reason to use one or the other(onDone vs onError)? Maybe someone can add it to the answer?

Comment: The `onError` parameter is set to accept a `Function` (the super-type of all functions) rather than a specific function type. That's because it accepts both `void Function(Object)` and `void Function(Object, StackTrace)`, and there is no way to represent that type union in the Dart type system. The remaining parameters can be typed with the specific function type needed.

Comment: As it's a little bit hidden in the answer, this is how to pass a typed function with return type as parameter in another function: `int outerFn(bool Function(String, bool) innerFn) { final result = innerFn("123", true); }`

Comment: Why not `Function<int>` ?!!! ... Flutter is not intuitive....

Comment: What would you expect `Function<int>` to mean? Generally `<...>` is used for type arguments to generic declaration. You can write `T Function<T>(T)` for the type of generic functions that can map any type to itself.

Answer (score 37):

To strongly type a function in dart do the following:

1. Write down the `Function` keyword

```dart
Function
```

2. Prefix it with its return type (for example `void`)

```dart
void Function
```

3. Append it with parentheses

```dart
void Function()
```

4. Put comma separated arguments inside the parentheses

```dart
void Function(int, int)
```

5. Optionally - give names to your arguments

```dart
void Function(int foo, int bar)
```

Real life example:

```dart
void doSomething(void Function(int arg) f) {
    f(123);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Edit: Note that this answer contains outdated information. See [Irn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43611520/1340742) for more up-to-date information.

Just to expand on Randal's answer, your code might look something like:

```
typedef void IntegerArgument(int x);

void doSomething(IntegerArgument f) {
    f(123);
}
```

`Function<int>` seems like it would be a nice idea but the problem is that we might want to specify return type as well as the type of an arbitrary number of arguments.

Answer (score 12):

For reference.

```
int execute(int func(int a, int b)) => func(4, 3);

print(execute((a, b) => a + b));
```

Answer (score 10):

You can have a function typed parameter or use a `typedef`

```
void main() {
  doSomething(xToString);
  doSomething2(xToString);
}

String xToString(int s) => 's';

typedef String XToStringFn(int s);

void doSomething(String f(int s)) {
    print('value: ${f(123)}');
}

void doSomething2(XToStringFn f) {
    print('value: ${f(123)}');
}
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/55631a373f7de0efbfb27d31ab6890e1)

Answer (score 8):

This is what [typedefs](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs) are for!