# How to declare parameter with function type in dart

Tags: dart

E.g. in Typescript I'd have:

```
function foo(callback: (num) => string) {
  console.log(callback(1));
}
```

And even in C/C++ you can do it using an insane syntax:

```
void foo(string (*callback)(int)) {
  cout << callback(5) << "\n";
}
```

How do I do the same in Dart without resorting to `typedef`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a typed function as a parameter in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334714/pass-a-typed-function-as-a-parameter-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the function return type, and parameters in a way similar to when you define a function:

```
void foo(String callback(int n)) {
  print(callback(1));
}
```