# Lambda Expression as a function parameter in Dart Language

Tags: dart, lambda, parameters

I am trying to build a class to making some operations in *mathematical sequences* in **Dart** . And I am expecting a sequence as a **lambda expression** or **function** . I got confused when I try to build constructor of class . What should I write for parameters and data types ?

Sample **lambda expression** :

> `int sequence(int n) => 7+5*(n-1);`

Sample function :

```
int fib(int n) {
  if ((n == 1) || (n == 2)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
  }
}
```

How can I give that lambda expression and function as a parameter to another function ?

Comment: you mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334714/pass-a-typed-function-as-a-parameter-in-dart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the type of your two methods are `int Function(int)` which means it takes one `int` as a parameter and outputs a `int`.

There are basically two ways to do it. One is to explicit type that type as a parameter type like:

```
int sequence(int n) => 7 + 5 * (n - 1);

int generate1(int Function(int) function, int input) => function(input);

void main() {
  print(generate1(sequence, 5)); // 27
}
```

Another way is to define a `typedef` which will be a shorthand for your type:

```
int fib(int n) {
  if ((n == 1) || (n == 2)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
  }
}

typedef SomeFunction = int Function(int n);
int generate2(SomeFunction function, int input) => function(input);

void main() {
  print(generate2(fib, 5));      // 5
}
```

The `typedef` can be easier if you have more complicated types you are reusing for multiple methods.