# How to pass a logger to logRequests in dart shelf?

Tags: dart, dart-shelf

I'm trying to use the logRequests function from shelf. Function is as follows:

```
Middleware logRequests(
    {void logger(String message, bool isError)?}
)
```

And implementation is like:

```
Middleware logRequests({void Function(String message, bool isError)? logger}) => ...
```

I'm calling logRequests here:

```
final handler = Pipeline().addMiddleware(logRequests()).addHandler(app);
```

And it works fine, but I want that optional logger function so I can do whatever I want with the  messages.
Problem is I can't seem to be able to pass a function as the argument here... I've searched how to pass functions as arguments but all I get is "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found".

I've tried define the function in a lot of ways, the last one (as seen in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334714/pass-a-typed-function-as-a-parameter-in-dart)) was:

```
void Function(String s, bool b) log() => (String s, bool b) => print('');
```

And calling it like:

```
final handler = Pipeline().addMiddleware(logRequests(log)).addHandler(app);
```

This and all the other things I've tried always gives me above mentioned error.

So how can I pass a function here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying more things, found how to do it.

Function:

`void _log(String msg, bool isError){ print('test Logger'); }`

Calling it:

`final handler = Pipeline().addMiddleware(logRequests(logger: _log)).addHandler(app);`